# If $H \triangleleft G$ and $p^k \mid [G:H]$ where $p$ is prime, there exists $K$ such that $[K:H] = p^k$.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

> $H$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$ such that $p^k \mid [G : H]$ where $p$ is prime and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that there exists a subgroup $K$ of $G$ such that $[K : H] = p^k$.

This is a problem from a book that I'm reading. I'm totally confused as to where to start and, specifically, how to employ the condition that $H$ is normal.

I was thinking of this approach: suppose that $\vert G \vert = p^{k + l}m$ for some $l \geq 0, p \nmid m$ and $\vert H \vert = p^n$. Then a subgroup $K$ of order $\vert K \vert = p^{k + n}$ exists by the First Sylow Theorem. The left cosets of $K$, say ${K_1, K_2, ..., K_N}$, partition $G$. WLOG assume $\exists h \in H: h \in K_1$. Perhaps it is now possible to show that $H < K_1$, but that seems overly optimistic, as it would be quite a strong statement. There's also the obvious problem with assuming that $\vert H \vert$ is a power of $p$ -- I don't see how to generalize that.

I don't necessarily need a solution, just an idea maybe. Thank you.

Comment: Use Sylow on the quotient and then lift. Note that $G$ is not assumed finite, so you cannot assume $|G|=p^km$.

Comment: Taking $H=\{e\}$ gives the first Sylow Theorem, so it is unlikely you are expected to do tjis without Sylow.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun this is Allan Clark's Elements of Abstract Algebra.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you! It's very obvious now that I look at it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, $k$ is not stated to be the maximal power of $p$ dividing the order of the quotient group. I don't think this bothers, as subgroups exist for every power from the maximal one to zero, but I'm unsure this can still be named "Sylow".

Comment: @fitzcarraldo There are several versions of Sylow's First Theorem. Here's the one in Marshall Hall's "Theory of groups", for example: "If $G$ is of order $n=p^ms$, where $p\nmid s$, $p$ a prime, then $G$ contains subgroups of order $p^i$, $i=1,\ldots,m$, and each subgroup of order $p^i$, $i=1,\ldots,m-1$ is a normal subgroup of at least one subgroup of order $p^{i+1}$."  As I recall, Hungerford's statement likewise includes the existence of subgroups of order $p^i$ for $i=0,1,\ldots,m$.

Comment: I see, though Herstein's *Topics in algebra* explicitly claims otherwise, and the very name of "Sylow $p$-subgroups" for only the maximal ones makes this plausibile.

Comment: @fitzcarraldo I do not know how Sylow stated it initially. I've seen both versions for the First Theorem (Isaacs gives one that does not include all orders, just the maximal one, for instance).

Comment: @fitzcarraldo In the book I've mentioned, it is stated that Sylow originally discovered his First Theorem only for the maximal subgroup, but it has since been generalized to all powers of $p$. It seems like this generalized theorem is the one most often stated in modern texts.